# Tab/Window group movement: (Ctrl-W)(Ctrl-L), etc

Tags: vim, visual-studio-2013, vsvim

I noticed that in the list of [supported features](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/Supported-Features) for VsVim tab group movement was listed.

I've been trying to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, but I haven't been able to get them to move between tabs. I was wondering if I needed to do anything in the settings to get this to work properly.

I'm currently using the VsVim on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I don't believe that moves between tabs. Its the same as `<C-W>l` which moves to the window/split to your right. If you want to change tabs I think you want to use `gt` or `gT`. However that doesn't seem to be on your supported list.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to get it to move between windows/splits. (I thought they were called tab groups) I can move between tabs just fine with gt and gT, but I'm unable to use the above commands to move from one vertical split to another.

Comment: Have you tried using `<Ctrl-W>l` as opposed to `<Ctrl-W><Ctrl-l>`?

Comment: Yes, <Ctrl-W>l does nothing and says "Not Implemented" in the VsVim Command Line

Comment: @Epenetus Considering that is listed on the supported features I would assume you have not updated to the latest version or you found a bug/regression. Does vsvim have a bug tracker?

Answer (score 2):

For a long time, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> were not implemented. [I have implemented them](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/pull/1472) and they should be available as of the next release of VsVim. They do work across tab groups. In the meantime, if you are anxious to have them, you could grab an AppVeyor build.

Also <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> are available already. However, they don't move between tab groups; they move between actual Visual Studio horizontal window splits. It is tough to map Vim buffers/windows/tabs onto Visual Studio tabs/tab groups/splits/documents...